# android webservice ksoap2 mistake

Tags: android, web-services, soap, ksoap2

im trying to test a webservice made for me and when i try on android i have a problem.
I read all the posts and i cant resolve it.
Here is my code:

```
import java.io.IOException;

import org.ksoap2.SoapEnvelope;
import org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapObject;
import org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapPrimitive;
import org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapSerializationEnvelope;
import org.ksoap2.transport.HttpTransportSE;
import org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserException;

import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.TextView;


import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;

public class ListIncidencesActivity extends Activity {



private static final String NAMESPACE = "http://localhost:8080/";
private static String URL="http://localhost:8080/WebApp/services/Hola?wsdl";
private static final String METHOD_NAME = "DiHola";
private static final String SOAP_ACTION ="http://localhost:8080/DiHola";

private SoapObject request=null;
private SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope=null;
private SoapPrimitive  resultsRequestSOAP=null;

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_list_incidences);        

        request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME);
        request.addProperty("nombre","R1K4R2");

        envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);

        envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);

        HttpTransportSE transporte = new HttpTransportSE(URL);

        try {
            transporte.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);

            resultsRequestSOAP = (SoapPrimitive)envelope.getResponse();

        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (XmlPullParserException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        Log.v("Milagro?","SIIII  "+ resultsRequestSOAP);    
      }
}
```

When I add the library `ksoap2-android-assembly-2.5.8-jar-with-dependencies` I get a fatal error when run:

```
01-25 04:46:38.374: E/AndroidRuntime(781): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-25 04:46:38.374: E/AndroidRuntime(781): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapObject
01-25 04:46:38.374: E/AndroidRuntime(781):  at es.proyecto.gestorincidencias.ListIncidencesActivity.onCreate(ListIncidencesActivity.java:47)
01-25 04:46:38.374: E/AndroidRuntime(781):  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5008)
01-25 04:46:38.374: E/AndroidRuntime(781):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1079)
01-25 04:46:38.374: E/AndroidRuntime(781):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2023)
01-25 04:46:38.374: E/AndroidRuntime(781):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2084)
01-25 04:46:38.374: E/AndroidRuntime(781):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:130)
01-25 04:46:38.374: E/AndroidRuntime(781):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1195)
01-25 04:46:38.374: E/AndroidRuntime(781):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
01-25 04:46:38.374: E/AndroidRuntime(781):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
01-25 04:46:38.374: E/AndroidRuntime(781):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
01-25 04:46:38.374: E/AndroidRuntime(781):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-25 04:46:38.374: E/AndroidRuntime(781):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
01-25 04:46:38.374: E/AndroidRuntime(781):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
01-25 04:46:38.374: E/AndroidRuntime(781):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
01-25 04:46:38.374: E/AndroidRuntime(781):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

If i update to `ksoap2-android-assembly-2.6.5-jar-with-dependencies` i get problem to compile:

```
The import org.ksoap2 cannot be resolved
```

but is different that when i dont have anyone added (wire). appear a ! signal in mi icon project.

So any idea?? i hope is a small mistake that i cant see because i have no experience and its my first time.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: maybe my ksoap2-android-assembly-2.6.5-jar-with-dependencies is corrupt?? whats the link go get it? i dont understand ;D

Comment: FIXED ADDING THE SAME ksoap2-android-assembly-2.6.5-jar-with-dependencies TO "ORDER AND EXPORT" next to library

Answer (score 0):

Read [this](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/88b6e5/how-to-call-web-service-in-android-using-soap/) link and follow the instruction how to place the .jar file and dont to forget to give proxy address as Right click on "project" -> Run As -> Run Configuration Proxy -> your internet access IP address
port    -> default 8080

Then click on "Apply".

Answer (score 0):

click on android project open right menu then select build path and select configure build path

there check order and support where your your assembly  ksoap2-android-assembly-2.6.5-jar-with-dependencies checked or not